# Почему не работает код на python (Не считывает из файла строки)

Tags: python, файлы

```
from selenium import webdriver

def Parser(driver_1):
    site = driver_1
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\gogis\Desktop\Python\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(site)
    
    # Screenshot 
    screenshot = driver.save_screenshot(r"C:\Users\gogis\Desktop\Python\PrintScreen\15.png")




def main():
    with open ("tmp.txt", 'r') as f:
        drver_1 = f.readline()
        drver_2 = f.readline()
        drver_3 = f.readline()
        print(drver_1)
    # Parser 15 min 
    Parser(drver_1)
    

    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print()
```

Comment: Что значит «не считывает»? Что происходит вместо считывания? Ваш `print(drver_1)` ничего не выводит или как?

Comment: Да, ничего не выводит просто пустую строку, хотя файле имеются строки

Comment: А если `print([drver_1, drver_2, drver_3])` то что выведет?

Comment: Тоже ничего не выводит

Comment: А, ну да, я только сейчас заметил, вы же функцию `main()` нигде не вызываете

Comment: Спасибо, я понял в чем дело (P.S. новичок, считай только начал учить этот язык)

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # тут Вы просто выводили пустую строку, не взаимодействуя с main()
    main()
```

Comment: Не нужно копировать весь код, если вы добавляете одну строку. Достаточно было нижнего блока.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Поправил